# Bootstrap custom markup with javascript functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How to take advantage of bootstrap javascript functionality with custom html markup, for example I have this html markup for dropdown menus

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="button button-success" id="dropdownButtonExample" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-list" aria-labelledby="dropdownButtonExample">
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item"><a class="dropdown-link" href="#">Dropdown item 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and I want to target the functionality of bootstrap dropdown;

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do. Please clarify.

Comment: You'd have to rewrite Bootstraps code to fit your new markup which isn't recommended. If you're going to all the trouble of rewriting how Bootstrap works, you might as well make your own functionality.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for clarifying my question!